# Find the correct PATH for MySQL and Cassandra

Tags: mysql, sql-server, batch-file, cassandra

I have a `.BAT` file for db backup that is setting up the paths for the sql server and cassandra, if the user don't install those applications in the same path the Backup it's going to fail.

Actually the `.BAT` file sets up the paths as follows:

```
SET "CASSANDRA_DATA_PATH=C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\data\data"
SET "MSSQL_BACK_PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup"
```

So, if the user has another version of SQL Server the backup is not going to work neither.

Instead of that, the `.BAT` file should find the correct paths and versions before executing the script.

**Any idea how to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this:

> sc \%HOSTIP% start RemoteRegistry
>   REG QUERY \\%HOSTIP%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders /s /f "DataStax" > search.txt
>   findstr  "ty\data" search.txt > testcase.txt
>   sc \HOSTIP stop RemoteRegistry

Answer (score 0):

If the Casandra is not some kind of portable database , after its installation it should store information about itself in registry somewhere under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\` . I'd never used casandra so you'll need to find by yourself where the data is stored. As for the MS SQL:

```
    @echo off 


    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions"') do set "ver=%%~nxa"
    rem for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions"') do set "ver=%%~nxa"
    echo --%ver%--
    rem set "ver=%ver:.=%"
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\%ver%" /v "ParentInstance"') do set "pi=%%~nxc"
    rem echo --%pi%--
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\%pi%\MSSQLServer" /v "BackupDirectory"') do set dbp=%%~nc


    echo %dbp%
```

this should echo the back-up directory if its set.

Comment: Hi   

Thanks for the reply! I couldnt find the registry lines you used in you example, but I found a registry key that gives me the **PATH** where the SQL was installed:

>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\Setup\ 

the registry value is called **SQLDataRoot** 

and it displays:  

>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL

Comment: @MidnightToker - rather open regedit and see where the backup location is.Could vary from machine to machine and you need to do something that will apply to your landscape.